# Array with characters as key, default value to 0

Tags: c++

I am creating an array in C++:

```
int my_array[100];
```

I want to use the array `my_array[a], my_array[b] ...` with characters in place of numbers. All works well, but my program will make `my_array[a]++; my_array[b]++;` etc., but the default value of each element is not 0, and I don't understand why.

I tried

```
int my_array[100]={0};
```

but with no success, and I dont want to declare each element as `my_array[a]=0;myarray[b]=0; ...`

How can I do this?

Comment: What are `a` and `b`? Are they out of bounds?

Comment: Maybe you want `my_array['a'-'a']` etc?

Comment: a and b are charecters. I want to use my_array[a], my_array[b],...,my_array[z] as in php.

Comment: Do you mean `my_array['a']`? That's certainly out of bounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `c` is a `char` variable, you can do `c - 'a'` to transform it into an index of `array`:

```
array[c - 'a'] = 0;
```

This works because:

```
'a' - 'a' == 0
'b' - 'a' == 1
'c' - 'a' == 2
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're expecting the array items all to be initialised to zero, in which case, declare it with: -

```
int my_array[26] = {0}
```

Note that if you want an array of characters, you can do that, instead of using an array of integers:

```
char my_array[26] = {static_cast<char>(0)};
```

Comment: Thank you, but the array keys are characters. The default value is not 0 for each element. I am using my_array[a], my_array[b] here a and b are simply characters. I am learning c++, and this was ok in php.

Comment: If you want characters, create an array of characters: char my_array[26];

Comment: What do you expect the default characters in the array to be initialised to?

Answer (score 1):

`my_array[a]` is valid in `C` only if `a` is a variable of an integer type (`char`, `int` aso).

If you want to use the `'a'`, `'b'`...`'z'` characters as keys in the array then you have to keep in mind that the `'a'` character is, in fact, the number `97` (which is the `ASCII` code of the `'a'` character). Similar, `'b'` is `98`, `'c'` is `99` and so on.

You can either declare `my_array[]` bigger, to have room for indices `97`..`122` (`a` to `z`) or you can shift the keys and use `0` for `a`, `1` for `b` and so on.

The latter is the usual approach in `C`, `C++` and other languages that use the word `array` for contiguous memory blocks of identical typed values. `PHP` arrays are, in fact, maps (aka dictionaries, hashes) combined with double-linked lists and not arrays at all.

Your code should look like:

```
int my_array[26] = {0};

my_array['a'-'a'] = 2;
my_array['b'-'a'] = 4;

char ch = 'm';

my_array[ch-'a'] = 123;
```

---

*As a side note, even in `PHP`, the expression `$my_array[a]` is incorrect unless a constant named `a` is defined. If you want to use the `'a'` character as a key then the correct syntax is `$my_array['a']`. If a constant named `a` is not defined then `PHP` issues a notice and converts the `a` undefined symbol into the `'a'` string and uses it instead.*